# Присвоение массиву значений другого массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, map, замена

Имеется массива вида

```
photos: [{img:'', type: ''},....{}]
```

Нужно присвоить значения из ключей img, type другому массиву с ключами:

```
links: [{image:'', imgType:''},...{}]
```

Как такое реализовать, либо просто переименовать ключи первого массива на нужные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, можно так:

```js
const photos = [{img: 'a', type: 'b'}, {img: 'c', type: 'd'}];

const links = photos.map(({ img, type }) => ({ image: img, imgType: type }));

console.log(links);
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо)